# How to send auto generated email Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, html-email

Background: This is largely a learning exercise.  I am working on a task scheduling program.  I have been asked to make it so that the application I am working on will send emails to users telling them they have messages waiting to be looked at.  I already have the part that sends emails working right, but that only works when the user is actively on a page.  I essentially want to make it so that the server decides to send emails at a certain time for instance midnight to tell users how many messages and meetings they have unread updates on during that day.  I am not familiar with how to make the app do work when not receiving input from the user.

What I am looking for:    How do I make ASP run a function on at a scheduled time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we had difficulties with the functionality of a browser when scheduling the browser (starting with a specific page) on the server.

A Temporary solution was to make one page in your project that reloads after waiting 5 minutes `<META http-equiv='refresh' content='6000'>`, and start this page on a client or on the server. Note: The copy running on the server stops when rebooting the server.

The final solution was to make a .Net package using the right server-side objects, and schedule this package in task scheduler.

Comment: Great simple solution.  Would vote up but my rep is too low.

Answer (score 1):

Use Windows Schedule Task to get IE to run the page at a scheduled interval.
e.g.

[image: Scheduled Task]

You will have to make sure that it runs unattended and with an account that is allowed to run it.  Also you will want the page to close the window after having finished.

(How to configure and what Schedule Task looks like varies depending on your Windows Version)

Comment: Great simple solution.  Would vote up but my rep is too low.